# Which Framework or tool Mozilla uses to develop their products?

Tags: firefox, frameworks, desktop-application

I know this is not related to programming but I am curious to know about which Framework or tool (like we use .NET Framework to develop desktop application interface) mozilla uses to develop their products like "Firefox", "Thunderbird" etc.

I like the interface of their applications the buttons especially looks cool and light weight. In first look their application and interface looks light weight. Whereas in .NET frameworks desktop applications, buttons looks heavy they are not having effects like moziila have on their interface.

Can anyone tell me what they uses and can i use the same to develop my applications?

Comment: Wow, you find Moz apps to be light weight? Try chrome, it will blow your mind

Comment: I used chrome, its lighter than moz apps, but in which language it is actually developed, which platform they have used to make the chrome??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their UI is based on XUL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL). You can use a program called XULRunner to create similar applications.

Comment: Is their any tool, to create applications in XUL, as we do in .NET??

Comment: If you're asking for a WYSIWYG user interface editor, then no, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

The UI they use is all based on XUL, the programming is done in just c++.

[Xul](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_Joy_of_XUL)

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla uses [XUL](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/xul/) to create UI for Firefox and Thunderbird.
You can think of XUL like a kind of HTML and CSS.